# Can't detect collision with child and ground

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collision

I have the below script attached to the ground game object to detect collisions from my players' child objects but for some reason, the collisions are not detecting.

My player (parent, empty game object) has a Rigidbody and Jump script attached to it, meanwhile, the child game objects (body & feet) have just box colliders on them.

Would love to know why this isn't working :)

```
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Body")
    {
        Debug.Log("Game over!");
    }
    else if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Feet")
    {
        Debug.Log("Alive!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a Rigidbody to the feet and the body. If you don't want them affected by physics, set isKinematic to true.  A child object doesn't inherit its parent's Rigidbody component.

Comment: I've done this already, but the player seems to fly around randomly on pushing play.

Comment: The flying around randomly thing will happen if you have two objects with rigidbodies and colliders overlapping when you press play, however, if both of those objects' rigidbodies have Is Kinematic checked, then they shouldn't interact with each other.  If one or both have Is Kinematic unchecked then one or both will fly around.

Comment: I've applied Rigidbodies to the child objects and the player is no longer flying around like a maniac which is great! But I can no longer move the player, would I need to apply the movement script on all of the child objects that I applied a rigidbody to?

Comment: It depends on how you've implemented movement.  Without more details about how you've set things up, it's too difficult to answer.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back. Here's the set up I have at the moment with the player: 

The parent gameobject (empty gameobject) has a Rigidbody and movement script, rest of child gameobjects such as the body and feet just have box colliders. 

When I attach a rigidbody to the body and feet and set them both to kinematic the player flies around randomly on pushing play.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, it works when you do collision.collider.tag instead of collision.gameobject.tag, like so:

```
if(collision.collider.tag == "Head")
        {
            Debug.Log("Game over!");
        }
```

Not exactly sure why this works, but it works! Defo going to look into this a bit more.